# what is the ajax url to get new table content?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to do a home project that consists in a desktop application with some info and stats from a website.

This is the link of the information: http://www.fpb.pt/fpb2014/!site.go?s=1&show=jui&id=5144

I want to have the first table content (ÚLTIMOS JOGOS REALIZADOS) in my application, my problem is getting the content that only appears when you press the next arrow.

My ideia was to find the ajax url to get the next content, but I dont manage to find how its done... The only ajax url that I found was this:

http://www.fpb.pt/fpb2014/do?com=DS;1;317.101000;++ID(5144)+BL(ULTIMOS_JOGOS);+MYBASEDIV(dJuiz_Ficha_Home_Jogos);+RCNT(2444445)+RINI(44443)&

But it only gets me the initial table content, can anyone tell me how I get the next table content?

Comment: You're going to have to reverse-engineer the functionality of the site you're trying to scrape.  Use the site, capturing and examining requests and responses in your browser's debugging tools.  Every HTTP request will be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. http://www.fpb.pt/fpb2014/do?com=DS;1;317.101010;++CO(JOGOS_REALIZADOS)+BL(JOGOS)+K_ID_JUIZ(5144)+MYBASEDIV(JuizJogos_JOGOS_REALIZADOS);+RCNT(10)+RINI(11)&
2. http://www.fpb.pt/fpb2014/do?com=DS;1;317.101010;++CO(JOGOS_REALIZADOS)+BL(JOGOS)+K_ID_JUIZ(5144)+MYBASEDIV(JuizJogos_JOGOS_REALIZADOS);+RCNT(10)+RINI(21)&

**+RINI(XY)** is the part that varies, where X is the page number

**Update (How to do it for yourself)**

1. Open chrome dev tools (F12)
2. Click on the network tab
3. Click on the link you're interested in
4. Look at the requests in the network tab.
5. Compare then in Notepad or what ever editor you want

Link [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network)

Comment: Thank you, thats it! I will accept your answer!

Comment: Thanks again, specially for the teaching. Have a nice day!